# SpringBoot Test NullPointer Exception

Tags: spring-boot, junit, jparepository

I am trying to test whether my SpringBoot Repository works adding the new User to database and I am getting a NullPointer Exception during the Junit test. Here is the code.

User:

```
package org.example;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringBootConfiguration;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name="users")
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    @Column(nullable=false, unique=true)
    private int creditCardNumber;

    @Column(nullable=false, unique=true)
    private String email;

    @Column(nullable=false)
    private String password;

}
```

UserRepository:

```
package org.example;

import org.example.User;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringBootConfiguration;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;


@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long>{

}
```

UserService:

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringBootConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
@SpringBootApplication
@Service
public class UserService {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    public User createUser(Long id, int credit_card_number, String email, String password) {
        User user = new User(id,credit_card_number,email, password);
        return userRepository.save(user);
    }
}
```

and UserTest:

```
package org.example;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;

@SpringBootTest
public class UserTest {


    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;


    @Test
    public void testCreateUser() {
        User newUser = userService.createUser(Integer.toUnsignedLong(23), 203952, "john@john.com", "siofd");
        assertEquals(newUser.getEmail(), "john@john.com");
    }
}
```

My testing is throwing nullpointer exception during testCreateUser because I think in UserService, UserRepository is null.

I added the repository annotation to UserRepository. I tried adding the @SpringBootApplication. Could you maybe help why.

Answer (score 0):

1. You should not put **@SpringBootApplication** on your UserService class.
   This annotation should be on your main application class only.
2. Use on top of your test class **@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)** for junit 5 and **@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)** for junit 4.
3. For me your test should look like this:

   ```
   @ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
   @SpringBootTest
   public class UserServiceIntegrationTest {

   @Autowired
   private UserService userService;

   @Autowired
   private UserRepository userRepository;

   @Test
   public void testCreateUser() {
       // given
       int creditCardNumber = 203952;
       String email = "john@john.com";
       String password = "siofd";

       User newUser = userService.createUser(null, creditCardNumber, email, password);

       User foundUser = userRepository.findById(newUser.getId()).orElse(null);
       assertThat(foundUser).isNotNull();
       assertThat(foundUser.getEmail()).isEqualTo(email);
       assertThat(foundUser.getPassword()).isEqualTo(password);
       assertThat(foundUser.getCreditCardNumber()).isEqualTo(creditCardNumber);
   }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

#### Fix UserService

First things first, please remove the `@SpringBootApplication` annotation from your `UserService` service.

#### Create a SpringBootApplication Annotated Class

Next, please create a class with a `main` method as entrypoint and annotate it with `@SpringBootApplication`. An example:

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringSandboxApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringSandboxApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Name `SpringBootApplication` class as you wish.

#### JUnit5 Sample Test

For the `UserService` a minimum working integration test with JUnit5:

```java
@SpringBootTest
class UserServiceIT {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Test
    void testCreateUser() {
        User createdUser = userService.createUser(1L, 1234567890, "test@test.com", "password");
        User retrievedUser = userRepository.findById(1L).orElse(null);

        assertEquals(createdUser.getId(), retrievedUser.getId());
        assertEquals(createdUser.getCreditCardNumber(), retrievedUser.getCreditCardNumber());
        assertEquals(createdUser.getEmail(), retrievedUser.getEmail());
        assertEquals(createdUser.getPassword(), retrievedUser.getPassword());
    }
}
```

Depending on your `pom.xml` you may need to add [Maven Failsafe Plugin](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/) definition to automatically run your integration tests invoking `mvn`:

```xml
<plugins>
    <build>
        <!-- your other plugin definitions -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.2</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>integration-test</goal>
                        <goal>verify</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Results of `mvn verify`:

```
2024-01-05T12:05:12.752+01:00  INFO 56206 --- [           main] c.g.t.s.service.UserServiceIT            : Started UserServiceIT in 1.462 seconds (process running for 1.894)
[INFO] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 2.015 s -- in com.github.tcsizmadia.springsandbox.service.UserServiceIT
[INFO] 
[INFO] Results:
[INFO] 
[INFO] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
[INFO] 
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- failsafe:3.1.2:verify (default) @ spring-sandbox ---
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  3.708 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2024-01-05T12:05:13+01:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```